# Substituting or summing based on condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data-manipulation, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha","Alpha","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta"), 
                 "Year" = c(1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1977,1978,1990), 
                 "Group" = c(1,NA,1,NA,NA,2,2,NA),
                 "Val" = c(2,3,3,5,2,5,3,5))
```

And I would like to create a cumulative sum of "Val". I know how to do the simple cumulative sum

`df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(cumval=cumsum(Val))`

However, I would like my final data to look like this

```
final <- data.frame("id" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha","Alpha","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta"), 
                 "Year" = c(1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1977,1978,1990), 
                 "Group" = c(1,NA,1,NA,NA,2,2,NA),
                 "Val" = c(2,3,3,5,2,5,3,5),
                 "cumval" = c(2,5,6,11,2,7,5,10))
```

The basic idea is that when two "Val"'s are of the same "Group" the one happening later (Year) substitutes the previous one. 
For instance, in the sample dataset, observation 3 has a "cumval" of 6 rather than 8 because of the "Val" at time 1972 replaced the "Val" at time 1970. similarly for Beta.

I thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Something like `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(cumval = cumsum(replace(Val, duplicated(Val), first(Val))))`

Comment: Because val at time 1972 (3) is "group" 1 like val at time 1970 (2). Basically, for val within the same group the latter value takes the place of the previous.  Hence here val 1972 takes the place of val 1970 ( and it is summed with val 1971) that is a different group (NA)

Comment: sure: obs 1: cumval = val =2, obs 2:  cumval = val(obs1) + val(obs2) =2+3=5, obs 3: cumval = val (obs2) +val(obs3) = 3+3 = 6... etc..the idea is that because obs 1 and 3 are of the same group, and id obs 3 takes the place of obs 1

Comment: or if it is more clear. cumval (obs3)= cumval(obs2) + val (obs3)-val(obs1) = 5+3-2=6

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. I don't think the lag is the right way to go because it the values to substitute are sparse. sometimes several year passes between the two val I need to substitute. Perhaps a way to tackle the problem (but I am not sure about the syntax) is telling r that when "id","Year" and "group" match, it should add the later Val (e.g. Alpha 1972, and subtract the earlier Val (Alpha 1970) to the cumsum it is calculating

Comment: Indeed, But NAs are cases that I am 100% sure have no value to substitute. Meaning it is ok to simply add them as comsum. if an id has an NA group, it means I do not have to substitute the val when calculating the cumsum. Only when I have matching "Group" it means that Val at some point has to be substituted (obs1) or it is the value to substitute it with (obs3). or obs(6) and obs(7)

Comment: Some description is confusing. `Val" at time 1972 replaced the "Val" at time 1970.` in that case, Val' would become `2 3 2` and cumsum would be `2 5 7`

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean with  `Val would become 2 3 2 and cumsum would be 2 5 7`. Indeed looking Val_1970=2, Val_1971=3, Val_1972=3. hence, simple cumsum would be 8 (2+3+3) but, given that both alpha Val_1970 and Val_1972 are in group 1. I would like cunsum only to compute Val_1972 instead of Val_1970 in the cunsum. hence it would be 6 (Val_1971+Val_1972).

Comment: to frame it differently. I want to calculate the total treatment value that a subject is facing. When groups are matching, the subject is changing its treatment. Prior to 1972 it had treatment (val 1970+1971). however in 1972 it changes treatment 1970 with treatment 1972. and I would like this to be reflected in the cumulative sum of treatements.

Comment: Ok, I tried couple of things, but still the 'Beta' part is not matching

Comment: Sorry, may be somebody else understands your logic better.

Comment: that is unfortunate! thanks for trying someting anyways..

Comment: would it be simpler if there were no NA's? so the data would look something like this?````df <- data.frame("id" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha","Alpha","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta"), 
                 "Year" = c(1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1977,1978,1990), 
                 "Group" = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2),
                 "Val" = c(2,3,3,5,2,5,3,5))````

Comment: Looks like  this has to be done in a recursive way for each row.  A `for` loop may be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my head, this requires a `for` loop. First we split the dataframe by the `id` column into a list of two. Then we create two empty lists. In the `og` list, we will put the row where the first unique non NA group identifier occurs. For `alpha` this is the first row and for `Beta` this is the second row. We will use this to subtract from the cumulative sum when the value gets substituted.

```r
mylist <- split(df, f = df$id)

og <- list()
vals <- list()

df_num <- 1
```

We shall use a nested loop, the outer loop loops over each object (dataframe in this case) in the list and the inner loop loops over each value in the Group column.

We need to keep track of the row numbers, which we do with the `r` variable. We initially set it to `0` outside the for loop so we add `1`. First we check if we are in the first row of the data frame, in which case the cumulative sum is simply equal to the value in the first row of the `Val` column. Then within the `if` test, we use another `if` test to check if the Group id is an NA. If it isn't then this is the first occurrence of the number that will indicate a substitution of the current value if this number appears again. So we save the number to the temporary variable `temp`. We also extract and save the row that contains the value to the `og` list.

After this it, goes to the next iteration. We check if the current Group value is NA. If it is, then we just add the value to the cumulative sum. If it isn't equal to NA, we check if the value is NA and is equal to the value stored in `temp`. If both are true, then this means we need to substitute. We extract the original value stored in the `og` list and save it as old. We then subtract the old value from the cumulative sum and add the current value. We also replace the orginal value in `og` with the current replacement value. This is because if the value needs to replaced again, we will need to subtract the current value and not the original value.

If `j` is NA but it is not equal to `temp`, then this is a new instance of Group. So we save the row with the original value to `og` list, and save the `Group`. The sum continues as normal as this is not an instance of replacing a value. Note that the variable `x` that is used to count the elements in the `og` list is only incremented when a new occurrence is added to the list. Thus, `og[[x-1]]` will always be the replacement value.

```r
for (my_df in mylist) {

  x <- 1
  r <- 0

  for (j in my_df$Group) {

    r <- r + 1

    if (r == 1) {

      vals[[1]] <- my_df$Val[1]

      if (is.na(j)==FALSE) {
        og[[x]] <- df[r, c('Group', 'Val'), drop = FALSE]
        temp <- j 
        x <- x + 1
      }

      next
    }

    if (is.na(j)==TRUE) {

      vals[[r]] <- vals[[r-1]] + my_df$Val[r]

    } else if (is.na(j)==FALSE & j==temp) {

      old <- og[[x-1]]
      old <- old[,2]

      vals[[r]] <- vals[[r-1]] - old + df$Val[r]
      og[[x-1]] <- df[r, c('Group', 'Val'), drop = FALSE]

    } else {

      vals[[r]] <- vals[[r-1]] + my_df$Val[r]
      og[[x]] <- my_df[r, c('Group', 'Val')] 
      temp <- j
      x <- x + 1

    }

    }

  cumval <- unlist(vals) %>% as.data.frame()
  colnames(cumval) <- 'cumval'
  my_df <- cbind(my_df, cumval)
  mylist[[df_num]] <- my_df
  df_num <- df_num + 1
}
```

Lastly, we combine the two dataframes in the list by binding them on rows with `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package. Then I check if the `Final` dataframe is identical to your desired output with `identical()` and it evaluates to `TRUE`

```
final_df <- bind_rows(mylist)
identical(final_df, final)
[1] TRUE
```